# Why stars are shown as crosses in some Hubble images?

Tags: hubble-telescope

Why the most luminous stars (point sources of light) like the ones in the image below are rendered as crosses? If they are artifacts generated by some Hubble instrument, what causes them? Can them be corrected in some way?

What does the orientation of the crosses depend on?

[image: Westerlund 1 supercluster]

([image source](https://www.nasa.gov/image-feature/goddard/2017/hubble-hones-in-on-a-hypergiants-home))